Loop manipulation subgroup of the braid group
Recently, I came across a subgroup of the braid group $B_{2n}$ that I'm calling the "loop manipulation" group $H_n$.
The idea is that we treat pairs of adjacent strands in the braid group as "loops" $i = 1, \dots, n$.
It is generated by the following elements:

$T_i$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$,
$C_i$ for $i = 1, \dots, n-1$
$P_i$ for $i = 1, \dots, n-1$.

The nomenclature is meant to suggest that
$T_i$ is a "twist", $C_i$ is a
"cross", and $P_i$ is a "pass".
Here is an illustration of the generators: The loop manipulation generators. (Also, there is a copy on my website here.) Generally, $H_n$ has a lot in common with the braid group $B_n$.
The $C_i$ generators are analogous to the the usual generators $\sigma_i$ of the braid group $B_{n}$ so we have:

The usual braid relation: $C_i C_{i+1} C_i = C_{i+1}C_iC_{i+1}$ for $i = 1, \dots, n-1$.
The usual braid commutation relation: If $|i - j| \geq 2$ then $C_iC_j = C_jC_i$

Playing with lots of little diagrams has convinced me of the following relations:

$T_iT_j = T_jT_i$ for all $i$ and $j$.
$T_iC_i = C_iT_{i+1}$ for $i = 1, \dots, n-1$.
$T_iP_i = P_iT_{i+1}$ for $i = 1, \dots, n-1$.

I've got two questions about $H_n$:

Do the relations above determine $H_n$ uniquely? To put it formally: If an abstract group
generated by $T_i$, $C_i$, and $P_i$ satisfied these relations, would it be
isomorphic to $H_n$?
Does this group appear in the literature anywhere?


If I've understood things correctly, you need to add the following relations: $P_i C_{i+1} C_i = C_{i+1} C_i P_{i+1}$, and $P_i P_{i+1} C_i = C_{i+1} P_i P_{i+1}$, and $P_i P_{i+1} P_i = P_{i+1} P_i P_{i+1}$.

Thanks. These seem like straightforward generalizations of the usual braid relation. How can I be sure that this list is complete?

You're thinking of $T_i = \sigma_{2i-1}$ every second braid (twist)?

I've seen this referred to as the Hilden subgroup of $B_{2n}$. E.g: arXiv:0706.4421 Theorem 5.3 gives a presentation in terms of your generators and 14 relations.

If you'd invert one of the $C_i$'s in equation (4) (which I understand you don't want to do) then the subgroup generated by the $C_i$ and $T_j$ is an affine braid group. More precisely, replacing your $C_i$ by something that's usually called $T_i$, which in addition obeys the quadratic relation $(T_i - q)(T_i + q^{-1})=0$, and writing $Y_i$ for your $T_i$, instead by  gives (the Bernstein–Zelevinsky presentation of) the affine Hecke algebra of type $GL_n$. (I'm not aware of an analogue of your $P_i$ in that case.)

Your group $H_n$ is (I believe) called the wicket group by Brendle and Hatcher in their paper Configuration spaces of rings and wickets.  They provide a presentation in Proposition 3.6.  They also provide two references that appear closely related; these are Hilden's 1975 paper and Tawn's 2008 paper.
